# WPF UI detach(pin out) functionality

Tags: wpf

Am looking to implement a detach and popup UI behaviour in my applcation.
It basically means that I will be displaying say, a stackpanel with lot elements on the right side of my page. And on a button click, I want the stackpanel part to popup(removing its allocated space in the UI) and should be able to move it above the underlying wpf UI.

What am trying to do is that remove the stackpanel from its parent grid on button click and add it as the child of wpf popup control. But I am facing some issues doing this way. However I just want to know whether I am doing it in the correct way or do anyone have a good alternative for implementing this pin out functionality am specified here?

Thanks,
Vinsdeon

Answer (score 1):

How about using this kinda nice control, `AvalonDock`, which is simulating Visual Studio's dockable components behaviors?

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

It will spare you the pain of developing such a specific functionality, and will have a great reusability anyway

Comment: I tried that already. But unfortunately my requirement is different. I don't want docking option at all. I think this not the one I want, as I need only the floating option and should strictly avoid docking options. I doubt if that is possible with the control.

Comment: If I remember well, it is. You have to use `Documents` and not `DockableContents`, you'll have the tabs + floating windows but no docking

Comment: Ok. I am busy with another work assigned to me. I will get back with a reply soon.